# Second succesive link is not displayed (links with URL at the end of the page)

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

While editing a [question on Ask Ubuntu] I noticed a bug:

```
> the link after [CMYK] [reference chart] is not displayed
[CMYK]:            https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model
[reference chart]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart
```

is rendered:

> the link after [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart) is not displayed

---

**Edit**     My wrong usage of markdown links is because the following works:

```
> Miswritten links are displayed anyway: [first] and [second]
[first]:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model
[second]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart
```

is rendered:

> Miswritten links are displayed anyway: [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) and [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not placed the link identifiers next to the link texts.
See the [help center formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) ("Links" section) for markdown usage.

So in your case, you would fix it like this:

> the link after `[CMYK][CMYK]` `[reference chart][reference chart]` is not displayed
>
> `[CMYK]:            https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model`
>   `[reference chart]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart`

Outputs:

> the link after [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) [reference chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart) is not displayed

---

You need the link text and the identifier together in separate brackets, then the identifier next to the link itself lower down the page.

For example:

> the link after `[CMYK][whatever_id_you_want]` `[reference chart][another_id]` is not displayed
>
> `[whatever_id_you_want]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model`
>   `[another_id]:           https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart`

Outputs:

> the link after [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) [reference chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart) is not displayed

---

Although, if you're going to use the same ID as the link text itself (i.e. `[CMYK][CMYK]`) then just using a numerical ID reference is fine.
Such as `[CMYK][1]`.

It's useful to use a unique identifier when it's a snippet (or different in some way) of longer text, for example:

`[The first answer I am linking to][answer-1]`
`[The second answer I am linking to][answer-2]`

Although *how* you use it is up to *you*, as long as it's used correctly :)

Answer (score 3):

Your markdown is incorrect, as pointed out by [James](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/230506/james), however there is a shorthand syntax you can use to avoid typing the identifier twice:

```
This is a [link][] and [another][].

[link]: http://example.com/hello
[and another]: http://example.com/world
```

which is rendered as:

> This is a [link](http://example.com) [and another](http://example.com/another).

Additionally, if you only need to use the link once, I'd recommend this simpler method instead:

```
This is a [link](http://example.com).
```

> This is a [link](http://example.com).